# Make javascript as function

Tags: javascript

i could not make it as function.Please help.When i modified as function and add button,it not work.

i'm newbie in javascript.i would like study by the simple script.But for the below script when i try to add "function xxx()" it not working with input button.

I try to solve by my own with google...failed.

```
 <script>
    var myStr = "xxx yyy zzz";
    var strArray = myStr.split(" ");

    // Display array values on page
    for(var i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++){
        document.write("<p>" + strArray[i] + "</p>");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @Nezamm, welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read the docs on "How to ask a good question" here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  Then edit this or ask again.  Specifically, you should post what you've tried, and specify what isn't working. Otherwise, it just sounds like you're asking someone to do your work for you.

Comment: Dear Dave, sorry for inconvenience that caused.

Answer (score 0):

Break your code into blocks if you ever are stuck on something. So first you are trying to break a string into an array so that's your first block. Then your second block would be to write it to the page. So we have our code basically written out in our heads.

```
---Break string
---Display broken string
```

So to make a function we need to write a function first

```
myFunction = function(){

};
```

But to get the function to be modular we need to be able to pass in `variables`

So we'll add two variables one being the string to pass through and one being the location to inject the looped broken text.

```
myFunction = function(str, location){

};
```

Now we have to do something with these variables.

```
myFunction = function(str, location){
   ///test if str is a string
   if(typeof(str) == "string")
   {
       var l = str.split(" "); /// here we're spliting the string into an array by every space
       if(l.length >= 1) ///test if there's atleast one item
            for(i=0;i<l.length;i++) ///simple for loop
                location.innerHTML += "This is a part of str " + l[i] + "<br>" ///you can do anything here you want to do.
   }
};
```

Now as you can see it's modular at it's lowest point, this can be as complex as you want it. here is a test you can try out and mess around with. https://jsfiddle.net/s8pytzm3/1/